# web.config locked by w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, web-config, locking

I've got a weird problem. It looks like if my IIS6 locked an application's web.config. If I try to edit it, Windows complains that the web.config is used by another process.

Using Process Explorer I can see that the file is owned by w3wp.exe. Removing the virtual directory and stopping the website wasn't useful at all.

Any idea (I cannot stop the whole server since a lot of sites are hosted in it)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what about restarting the server at night? a downtime of a few minutes for a greater cause!

Comment: ehehe if only I could bribe my sysadmin, I could try!

Comment: christopher, as far as I know IISReset will stop and restart IIS, which in a production server with multiple customers websites is not an option for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would try [stopping the application pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736923.aspx) for the website that is accessing the web.config.

Comment: I've tried that. I've moved the application to a new application pool do that I could stop it without affecting any other app, but with no luck.

Comment: the sysadmin recycled all the app pools, which is a very bad solution, but it worked. I am still perplexed.

Comment: @Simon's answer to open the text editor in administrator mode worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, stopping the application pool didn't help. I then tried launching my text edited as administrator, and then that allowed me to save the file. Unfortunately I don't know if I needed to stop the application pool or not in the end...

Comment: Running visual studio as administrator fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Best bet would be to rename the web config (maintianing the lock on that file) and recreating the file.  I'm not sure what would lock the file, but the app pool recycle should have freed the lock.

Comment: excuse me, I can't understand: for what I know you cannot rename a locked file...

Comment: Actually, you *can* RENAME a locked file.  You can't copy it, you can't move it, but you can change its name.  The lock will remain on the renamed file, allowing you to create a new web.config.

Comment: @Christopher_G_Lewis FYI, I'm having the same problem as the OP, and in this case its not letting me even rename the file.

Answer (score 0):

type **iisreset** in cmd will also solve this issue

Answer (score -1):

If you're using an x32 based system, you could try using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to 'unlock' the file, or possibly delete web.config and then recreate it.  Failing that, you could kill the w3wp.exe worker process, which should automatically restart.

Comment: using unlocker or stopping w3wp.exe on a production server is a No-No, according to the sysadmins...